# Facing problem to build boost using VS 2019 command tool

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I am facing a problem to build boost using visual studio 2019 command tool.
Below is the error :
Building Boost.Jam build engine
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'GZ' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9036 : use 'RTC1' instead of 'GZ'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/MLd'

Failed to build Boost.Jam build engine.
Please consult bjam.log for furter diagnostics.

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from

http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org
Please attach bjam.log in that case.

Comment: Which version of boost?

Comment: 1.42 version of boost

Comment: 1.42? A 10 year old version? It was never written/configured to compile with VS2019.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i require this specific configuration.
Thank you :)

Comment: Good luck with that... You are trying to build a complex library which is provided with various *makefiles* for different environment, with a development tool for which no such makefile is provided. You *just* have to correctly configure the makefile... My advice: find and use a pre-built binary....

Comment: ... Do not forget: boost tries to extend the standard library, if not the language itself. For that reason it cannot be clean and portable C++ but it requires tweaking for each environment. What you want is a complex task which requires both knowledge on boost sources and VS2019 flags.